# "AttributeError: 'Description' object has no attribute 'co_button'" with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm struggling for about 2 hours know.. I can't see what's wrong with the code. But it's giving me this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\82104\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\82104\PycharmProjects\Macro\GUI.py", line 365, in on_entry_trace
    self.co_button['state']=new_state
AttributeError: 'Description' object has no attribute 'co_button'
```

I have no idea what the first error about line 1705 means, but I can see from the second error that my function `on_entry_trace` cannot find `self.co_button`. However I cannot find why it can't. I found that many people had this problem because they wrote like

```
button = ttk.Button(something).grid(something)
```

instead of

```
button = ttk.Button(something)
button.grid(something)
```

but this is not my case.

This is the class I'm having trouble with.

```
class Description(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(Description, self).__init__(master=master)

        self.title('Description')
        self.grab_set()
        self.geometry('206x100')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.label_ds = ttk.Label(self, text='Enter Text').grid(column=0, row=0, pady=(12, 4))
        self.description = tk.StringVar()
        entry_ds = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=self.description)
        entry_ds.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=13, pady=(0, 4))
        entry_ds.focus()
        self.description.trace('w', self.on_entry_trace)
        self.description.set("")

        self.co_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Confirm', command=self.on_press_ds)
        self.co_button.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=4)

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy_ds)

        self.wait_visibility()
        hide_minimize_maximize(self)

    def on_entry_trace(self, *args):
        new_state = "disabled" if self.description.get() == "" else "normal"
        self.co_button.configure(state=new_state)

    def on_press_ds(self):
        description = self.description.get()
        if description:
            self.master.listbox.insert('end', '-- ' + description + ' --')
        self.destroy_ds()
        self.destroy()

    def destroy_ds(self):
        self.master.ds_button['state'] = 'normal'
        self.destroy()
```

Comment: Define the `Button` before the `Entry` widget. As `on_entry_trace` runs right after when you trace it. so either put `self.description.trace('w', self.on_entry_trace)` after the button or put button before the Entry widget

Comment: @saad that solved the problem right away! But why does the result change by defining the button before the entry widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because trace method of Entry widget `self.description.trace('w', self.on_entry_trace)` is calling `self.on_entry_trace` method before the declaration of `co_button`.

> I have no idea what the first error about line 1705 means

It the line from the main tkinter library where the `return self.func(*args)` failed to execute because of the line 365 in your file.

---

This is how it works

Python is reading like...

```
    ....

    entry_ds.focus()
    # This will execute after above line 
    self.description.trace('w', self.on_entry_trace)
    # Then goes through self.on_entry_trace()
    ...
      # This will execute next
      new_state = "disabled" if self.description.get() == "" else "normal"
      # And here it'll throw an error as there is no attribute 
      self.co_button.configure(state=new_state)
    ...

    self.description.set("")
    ....

    # And you declared your button here
    self.co_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Confirm', command=self.on_press_ds)
    self.co_button.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=4)
```

So by putting `self.description.trace('w', self.on_entry_trace)` at the end of your `__init__` will fix the error and also reduce the chances of future errors like this.

---

*Tip:*

The best way to put `binds` and `trace` or `after` is at end of the code to avoid these small errors. It can also depends on your strategy.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was ok because I put the function using ```co_button``` under the button. But it's not because I called the function before the button gets defined. Did I understood it correctly?

Comment: But you called the function before you defined `co_button`, it is like executing `co_button.config(...)` before `co_button = Button(...)`